# Admob not load ads

Tags: android, admob, ads

Advertising does not load and is not shown in my application. I tried to create another admob key for the application, but that did not help. This error is displayed in the logcat:

W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0 
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0

```
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), Parameters.ADS_KEY_ADMOB);
      mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
      mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(Parameters.ADMOB_ID_BLOCK);
      mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener() {
         @Override
         public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
         }
      });
      requestNewInterstitial();


    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);


    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    GameMain game = new GameMain(this);


    View gameView = initializeForView(game, config);

    layout.addView(gameView);


    setContentView(layout);


    }
    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
       AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
      mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
     }

    public void showInterstitial(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
         if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
         }
      }
    });
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.test.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Optional -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.test1.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>




        <meta-data android:name="com.appodeal.framework" android:value="gdx" />
        <receiver android:name="com.appodeal.ads.AppodealPackageAddedReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.InterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.VideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.LoaderActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

        <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

        <activity android:name="org.nexage.sourcekit.mraid.MRAIDBrowser"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />


        <activity android:name="com.amazon.device.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>

        <activity android:name="com.my.target.ads.MyTargetActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

        <activity android:name="org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VASTActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <activity android:name="org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VPAIDActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.networks.vpaid.VPAIDActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.networks.SpotXActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads2.adunit.AdUnitActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads2.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />


        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyOverlay"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyBrowser"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.vungle.publisher.FullScreenAdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.OverlayActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.FullScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <service android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaService" android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" android:process=":Metrica">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="com.yandex.metrica.IMetricaService" />
                <data android:scheme="metrica" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="metrica:api:level" android:value="44" />
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaEventHandler"
            android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.flurry.android.FlurryFullscreenTakeoverActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.VideoPlayerActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>

        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.revmob.FullscreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>

        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.TJAdUnitActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.mraid.view.ActionHandler" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.mraid.view.Browser" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.TJContentActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

At the same time, test advertising is shown normally

Comment: give it some time... It takes some time before real ads start showing... Test ads are displayed means your code is fine.. Make sure you are using correct banner/interstitial ID in code

Comment: Ads are not showing for 3 days

Comment: Have you set correct ID? Make sure you are not using account ID.. Also login to your Admob account and make sure all registration are filled up ( payment information, tax information etc ) and account is active.. If all above steps are correct.. Write to admob and they will guide you further

Comment: Have you tested your Ad placement with `.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);` ?